# Keeping a specific javascript (.js) file unbundled and non-minified during React Build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, create-react-app

I require a specific (.js) file to not be bundled part of main.chunk during React Build of Create React App. This requirement is specifically pertaining to a constants file where I keep the app specific constants. I'd like to keep the constants file hosted in production unbundled so that it could be possible for my client (who this React app belongs to) to be able to change the constant values directly to update the app. Is this possible? and hopefully not anti-pattern?